# Populate column until text changes in colored cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have about 100,000 lines of data in Excel and some coloured cells in column C which I want repeatedly to populate in column B up until the coloured cell contains different text, when I want to populate that different text, etc.  Example below:-

Before:

http://i61.tinypic.com/24q758n.png

After:

http://i59.tinypic.com/t6as9l.png

Are there any macros, VB scripts or "IF" statements I could use? It seems like a life time's work if done via copy 'n paste.

Comment: What have you tried so far? This can be done fairly easily using a macro. Try using the macro recorder and doing one or two manually, then come back with specific questions on how to make your code work if you can't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter to select the coloured cells, say in ColumnB. In ColumnA insert `=Bx` where `x` is the row number of the first row that has been coloured (repeat for other colours if necessary). Then select ColumnA, Copy, Paste Special, Values over the top and then select from Ax to end, HOME > Editing -Find & Select, Go To Special..., check Blanks, `=`, Up, Ctrl+Enter.

Comment: I am one step closer to this method. I basically done the following so far:
- FIltered by colour
- used formula =c2 to copy cells into the designated fields

the issue now lies when i try to replace the formula values with just "paste special -> values", in which, an error occurs:

selection is not valid - several reasons

copy n paste areas cannot overlap unless they are the same size or shape

if you clicked data table command you must select single rectangle that is more than one row high and more than one column wide

Comment: WOOOOOOOO!!!!! this worked :D Many thanks. Gosh didnt realise it was that simple. Thanks pnuts

Answer (score 1):

1. Select column C and choose Data ► Sort & Filter ► Autofilter. Use the filter pull-down in C1 to *Filter by color*.
2. In B2 put in the formula `=C2` and fill down to the extents of your data.
3. Click Data ► Sort & Filter ► Autofilter to remove the filter.
4. First select B2 to the bottom of the data then tap <kbd>F5</kbd>, click <kbd>Special</kbd> and choose *Blanks* then click **OK**.
5. B3 should be the active cell. Type `=B2` and finalize the formula with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. This will populate all of the blank cells with a relative copy of that formula.
6. Your column B should be populated as you described. Optionally use *Copy* then *Paste Special, Values* to revert the formulas to their results. Optionally color column B to be same as C2.